# How to call method with parameter of type vector<int>::iterator& in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a method to find number in range of iterator like below. I want it has reference parameter and return reference of iterator.

```
// find number in range of begin and end, if number found return reference of iterator, throw exception otherwise
vector<int>::iterator &find_int(vector<int>::iterator &begin, vector<int>::iterator &end, int &number)
{
    for (; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if (*begin == number)
        {
            return begin;
        }
    }

    throw "not found";
}
```

I want to call this method as following code but it can't compile.

```
vector<int>::iterator i5 = find_int(vi1.begin(), vi1.end(), 5);
```

I want to know how can I call `find_int` method ?

**Update**
Error message when compile the code

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c g++ c:\cpp\ch9.cpp -o c:\cpp\ch9.exe
c:\cpp\ch9.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c:\cpp\ch9.cpp:41:63: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of ty
pe 'std::vector<int>::iterator& {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vec
tor<int> >&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx:
:__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}'
c:\cpp\ch9.cpp:30:24: error: in passing argument 1 of 'std::vector<int>::iterato
r& find_int(std::vector<int>::iterator&, std::vector<int>::iterator&, int&)'
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Comment: How does that not work ? What error do you get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function really shouldn't be taking `iterator&`'s (or the `int&`<sup>1</sup>) anyway. It should take the arguments by value, and return the iterator by value.

Even if you didn't get a compiler error because of the int literal you're trying to pass it (`5`) where it expects an `int&`<sup>1</sup>, the reason you can't call it the way you're doing is because you would be passing a reference to a temporary value, then getting a reference to that temporary through the return value of the function, and by the next line of code, the reference would refer to a destroyed object.

You can call it like this:

```
vector<int>::iterator beg = vi1.begin(), end = vi1.end();

vector<int>::iterator& pos = find_int(beg, end, 5);
```

Note that `&pos == &beg`.

However, if this isn't a didactic exercise, I would recommend to do what shuttle87 suggested, which is to use `std::find`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks Ghita for pointing this out.

Comment: Actually the compile error is because you pass a reference to a temporary (e.g. 5) and you don't have const int number& (as a function parameter) in your find_int implementation. Otherwise your code should work

Comment: @Ghita ah, didn't see the `&` for the int parameter, didn't scroll to the right in his code block. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not a good idea to pass integral types by reference in this case because you don't modify number in this case and it makes the intent of the function deceiving.

Comment: @Ghita yes I know, I didn't write the code and made the same point about passing the iterators by reference.

Comment: Why it should take iterator by value? It's a bad practices or there are other reason? P.S. This is exercise in C++ book through.  

@Ghita: Why it's not good to pass integral type by reference?

Comment: @Anonymous because it doesn't force you to create two more variables for things that you probably don't need in the future (that is, you can't just pass it `vi1.begin()`, you actually have to make a variable to hold it). And besides, it's the common style, and it's the same style that is used throughout the STDlib.

Comment: Not a good practice to pass integral type by reference if you don't want it to be an output value because anyway the way function parameter passing in C/C++ is by coping the value of that int into that particular function and if you transmit a reference to an int or an int it's basically the same cost. Always pass by const Type & in case coping of that object is expensive or you want to make it clear that you have an input only parameter

Comment: Or even worse cost, because you add a level of indirection, so you perhaps add the time of dereferencing a pointer, which is worse than just accessing it directly on the stack.

Comment: @SethCarnegie : Thank you to clearify why it's better to pass by copy value.

Comment: @Anonymous remember that's just for this case though. In other cases it is very important or even necessary to pass by reference. You need to determine on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some reason you have to use your own code, I'd just use std::find like so:

```
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;
  // std::find returns iterator to vector element or end if not found:
  it = std::find (vi1.begin(), vi1.end(), 5);
  if(it == vi1.end()) throw "not found";
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use C++ 11 style:

```
auto res = std::find_if(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [num](int nb) -> bool {
        return (nb == num);
    });
```

Make sure to include "algorithm" header

Comment: Why is this more C++11 style than `std::find`? It's also probably less efficient.

Comment: Why would you say is less efficient ? It's more C++ 11 because you get to use lambdas

Comment: This is probably less efficient because it involves calling a function on every iteration if the compiler can't optimise it, and it's way less efficient to type. Also that's not a very good reason for being more C++11, find is not a second class citizen.

Comment: Any decent compiler will inline the lambda. It is not like that lambda function is used anywhere else so optimization aside don't see any reason not to use it. And it's quite efficient to type if you consider for example to find first element in a given range.

Comment: Maybe, but for this case, `auto i = find(begin(vi1), end(vi1), 5)` is much better than `auto i = std::find_if(begin(vi1), end(vi1), [num](int nb) -> bool {
        return (nb == num);
    });`. Anyway, +1 to this answer for an alternative way to do it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie tnx. You are right. I was just wanting to show a different way to do this.